# Filter Data for Each Row in a Column

Tags: filter, google-sheets

[EVE Online Manufacturing Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12E3kR1_Z4H05bOWjwZkcb-7Dt0LMCnlk_On0bnpqJ_M/edit?usp=sharing)

In Batch!F3:G, I'm attempting to break down the data input from columns B3:C to their components (and eventually materials/minerals in I3:J) by using filter to compare results in Engine!P:R. Multiplied of course by the total number of each finished product I need.

I've been trying to figure out ways to arrayformula this together, and even tried quite a few query functions without success. The best I've been able to come up with is to string the actual formula together, appending them with {}, but this gets bloated quickly. I need this to be open ended because I have a tendency to build a lot of things at once. Any help would be appreciated, even just point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on my limited knowledge about google sheet, I can only think of one way to do this automatically.

Here's a sheet I constructed based on your sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AfX8o05gUGPiN5S90w4o0yxuIYjsJRaXsaYUFTJuEPo/edit?usp=sharing

First, on Engine sheet, add one more column which will give you the number of materials required for that part, which is looked up in the PART LIST of BATCH sheet. For this I use `VLOOKUP`, as you see in D2.

Then on BATCH sheet, query the materials that `VLOOKUP` return positive, multiply it by the amount of item and then sum them. 
This is done by the `QUERY` used in F3

This method only if you don't have duplicate item in your PART LIST, due to the way VLOOKUP work.

Of course if you want to break the material list further, you can do the same approach..

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking to do. Batch!D3:D is already the multiple of the number of base items (Batch!A3:A) and the number of total iterations (Batch!A1).

Also, any item that is not found in Engine still needs to show up in Batch!:F3:F as well, because anything that is not broken down (in this case, those Republic Fleet parts) aren't actually built and must later be purchased from the in-game market. Lastly, I may end up having duplicate items in the part list. Brownie points if the query can sum duplicates, but it's not necessary.

Comment: You meant Batch!C3:C ? Yes, I assumed that that's the total amount of base items you need. That total amount is looked up and shown in Engine!D2:D through `VLOOKUP`. The query will then multiply that number with the amount of material that needed for the item, hence the "Select C*D" part in the inner `QUERY`, and them summed up by the outer `QUERY`. As for "any item that is not found in Engine still needs to show up in Batch!:F3:F as well", one easy way is that you can just add them into Engine list for the VLOOKUP to find, and the QUERY will return them right away, like I did.

Comment: Otherwise, we will have to either modify the `VLOOKUP` so that it will automatically add those items that does not fit anywhere up to the engine sheet, or modify the `QUERY` in which it will add those items that's not in the engine sheet over to the result. The first case is impossible since you cannot add rows by google sheet function ( Still can if you use script though ). As for second case, the query will become very complex it will take very long time to run.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been trying to make the nested query accept both the Engine range and ArrayFormula for its dataset simultaneously, but it keeps giving me errors. Not a big deal, just makes it easier to organize projects (by just duplicating/deleting tabs as needed rather than having to add more columns to the Engine tab for each one). Your solution is working great. Thank you. :)